# Confused!! Bean's lifecycle method chain

Tags: spring

```
public class Life implements BeanNameAware, BeanFactoryAware,  
    ApplicationContextAware, BeanPostProcessor, InitializingBean,  
    DisposableBean {  
private int counter; // counter  

public int getCounter() {  
    return counter;  
}  

public void setCounter(int counter) {  
    this.counter = counter;  
    System.out.println("1. Spring setter DI：" + this.counter);  
}  

public Life() {  
    System.out.println("0. Spring calls constructor");  
}  

@Override  
public void destroy() throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("8. DisposableBean#destroy：" + ++counter);  
}  

public void _destroy() throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("8'. bean#_destroy：" + ++counter);  
}  

@Override  
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {  
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime());  
    System.out.println("6. InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet："  
            + ++counter);  
}  

public void init() throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("6'. bean#init：" + ++counter);  
}  

@Override  
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)  
        throws BeansException {  
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime());  
    System.out  
            .println("5. BeanPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization："  
                    + ++counter);  
    return bean;  
}  

@Override  
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)  
        throws BeansException {  
    System.out  
            .println("7. BeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization："  
                    + ++counter);  
    return bean;  
}  

@Override  
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)  
        throws BeansException {  
    System.out.println("4. ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext："  
            + ++counter);  
}  

@Override  
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {  
    System.out.println("3. BeanFactoryAware#setBeanFactory：" + ++counter);  
}  

@Override  
public void setBeanName(String name) {  
    System.out.println("2. BeanNameAware#setBeanName：" + ++counter);  
}  
}
```

Code:

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("life.xml");  
        context.getBean("holder");  
    }  
}
```

Code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
    <bean id="life" class="test.Life" init-method="init"  
        destroy-method="_destroy">  
        <property name="counter" value="1" />  
    </bean>  
    <bean id="holder" class="java.lang.String" />
```

why the output is:

```
0. Spring calls constructor
1. Spring setter DI：1
2. BeanNameAware#setBeanName：2
3. BeanFactoryAware#setBeanFactory：3
4. ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext：4
**1320491454906
6. InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet：5
6'. bean#init：6**
1320491454921
5. BeanPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization： 7
7. BeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization：8
```

According to Spring in Action 3rd and Spring-Reference:

> > 6 If any of the beans implement the BeanPostProcessor interface, Spring calls
> >     their postProcessBeforeInitialization() method.
> >
> > 7 If any beans implement the InitializingBean interface, Spring calls their
> >     afterPropertiesSet() method. Similarly, if the bean was declared with an
> >     init-method, then the specified initialization method will be called.

It seems that there is something wrong with the order?!

Answer (score 1):

Methods of `BeanPostProcessor` (`postProcess...Initialization`) are called during initialization of other beans, not the post processor itself. Similarly, in your quote from Spring in Action `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` methods called at point 6 are methods of other `BeanPostProcessor`s declared in the context, not methods of the bean being initialized.

In your case these methods are getting called during initialization of `holder`.

So, `BeanPostProcessor` is a mechanism that allows a special-purpose bean (the post processor) to intercept initialization of other beans.

Comment: Thanks very much axtavt! I got it now.